# ASP.NET Calling Server Side Method from Client Side on keypress

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, client-server

To put it simply, I need a way for client side code to be able to trigger a server side method in my project. The way that I'm trying to use such functionality is when a user inputs their email address into a textbox, after each character is typed I want the project to trigger the method shown below which uses a class to query my database.

```
private void EmailCheck()
{
    lblEmailError.Text = null;
    Customer y = new Customer();

    int counter = 0;
    y.Email = Email.Text;

    counter = y.CheckEmail();
    if (counter.Equals(1))
    {
        lblEmailError.Text = "Email is already in use";
    }
    else
    {
        lblEmailError.Text = null;
    }
}
```

I currently have almost no experience of any kind with JavaScript or any form of client side scripting. As I understand, AJAX may be of use to me here but again I am clueless about how I would implement it. I've also heard about onkeydown/press/up but again I am not sure how to alter online solutions to my specific need. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to make a button in HTML5, use jQuery `$.ajax()` function to invoke a server side REST API (implementation could be anything C# Web API, Python Flask API, Node.JS API).

**In your client side:**

```
<label> Enter something into the textbox </label> 
<input type = "text" id = "myTextBox" placeholder="Enter something"/>


<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){

//On button click query the server

$("#myTextBox").change(function(){
var textBoxValue = $("#myTextBox).val();
var dataToBeSent = {
 "data": textBoxValue
}; 

$.ajax(function(){
url: "http://localhost:9999/api/YourAPIName",
method: "POST",
data: JSON.stringify(dataToBeSent),
success: function(data){
   console.log(data);
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
   console.log("Failed because" + errorThrown);
}
}); //end .ajax

}); //end click

}); //end jQuery
</script>
```

**In your Server side (Assuming C#):**

Make a model class, with properties the same name as the JSON key you constructed for the `[FromBody]` attribute to deserialize it correctly.

```
public class SomeModelClass
{
   public string data { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("api/YourAPIName")]
public HttpResponseMessage YourMethod([FromBody] SomeModelClass modelClass)
{
    //perform logic and return a HTTP response
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this but how would I edit this code to make it call the method when a character is entered into a textbox

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET MVC app?

Comment: No I created an empty web application

Comment: @N.Ali check my updated answer for sending textbox value to server side using jQuery and Web API.

Comment: However you still need to press the button to call the method. I want the method to be executed every time someone enters a character into the textbox.

Comment: @N.Ali you can use the [jQuery change() function](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp) to monitor the text box value every time the user clicks on it.